# UITabBarController with same ViewController in different tab

Tags: ios, uitabbarcontroller

**Scenario**:

1. We have a tab bar controller in the app.
2. Only one view controller has a different color style for the StatusBar, let's call this view controller **VC1**.
3. So I have added logic in **VC1**, viewWillAppear set the wanted StatusBar Color, viewWillDisappear reset the default StatusBar Color.

**Issue**:
Most of the time, different tabs have different view controllers, this is no issue of the status bar color changing.

But In one case, I will have VC1 shown in two tabs, in this case, **when I switch tab**, **viewWillAppear** got called **first**, which means the **reset StatusBar style** got called **later**, so after switching the tab, the StatusBar Color is wrong.

Is there a way to solve this? It seems the view controller life cycle is wrong in this scenario.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at `UITabBarControllerDelegate`. Using that, you can take action based on which tab is selected - such as changing the color of the StatsBar - instead of doing that inside the VC.

> You use the UITabBarControllerDelegate protocol when you want to
>   augment the behavior of a tab bar. In particular, you can use it to
>   determine whether specific tabs should be selected, to perform actions
>   after a tab is selected, or to perform actions before or after the
>   user customizes the order of the tabs.

ref: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitabbarcontrollerdelegate

Comment: I get your idea, it should work, but I have to make the logic specific on the view controllers since the style not simply dependent on tab only.